# I'm trying to connect my back end payment to my front end card charge with angular. How can I achieve this?

Tags: node.js, angular, deployment, payment-gateway, middleware

As you can imagine, stripe and authorize.net and other payment gateway services offer an api that can only be hit via server-side for safety reasons. Currently the documentation for Authorize.net allows for me to create an express node app and then run the command node charge-credit-card.js (which works and gets a 200 response from their api)  My question is two parts. How do I connect my server directory (aptly named named AuthorizePaymentNode in the image below this paragraph) with my angular src app directory(aptly named named FoodOrderingApp in the image) to gather the card info on the front end so that I may process a credit card from start to finish? Secondly assuming I get it working in development how and where do I upload my AuthorizePaymentNode directory along with my FoodOrderingApp so that the two work together. Do I do it in two separate places as a friend of mine suggested or can it just be done all at once and in one place?

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibUDr.png][1]

charge-credit-card.js (works like a charm when running node charge-credit-card.js)

```
var ApiContracts = require('authorizenet').APIContracts;
var ApiControllers = require('authorizenet').APIControllers;
var SDKConstants = require('authorizenet').Constants;
var utils = require('./utils.js');
var constants = require('./constants.js');

function chargeCreditCard(callback) {
    var merchantAuthenticationType = new ApiContracts.MerchantAuthenticationType();
    merchantAuthenticationType.setName(constants.apiLoginKey);
    merchantAuthenticationType.setTransactionKey(constants.transactionKey);

    var creditCard = new ApiContracts.CreditCardType();
    creditCard.setCardNumber('4242424242424242');
    creditCard.setExpirationDate('0822');
    creditCard.setCardCode('999');

    var paymentType = new ApiContracts.PaymentType();
    paymentType.setCreditCard(creditCard);

    var orderDetails = new ApiContracts.OrderType();
    orderDetails.setInvoiceNumber('INV-12345');
    orderDetails.setDescription('Product Description');

    var tax = new ApiContracts.ExtendedAmountType();
    tax.setAmount('4.26');
    tax.setName('level2 tax name');
    tax.setDescription('level2 tax');

    var duty = new ApiContracts.ExtendedAmountType();
    duty.setAmount('8.55');
    duty.setName('duty name');
    duty.setDescription('duty description');

    var shipping = new ApiContracts.ExtendedAmountType();
    shipping.setAmount('8.55');
    shipping.setName('shipping name');
    shipping.setDescription('shipping description');

    var billTo = new ApiContracts.CustomerAddressType();
    billTo.setFirstName('Ellen');
    billTo.setLastName('Johnson');
    billTo.setCompany('Souveniropolis');
    billTo.setAddress('14 Main Street');
    billTo.setCity('Pecan Springs');
    billTo.setState('TX');
    billTo.setZip('44628');
    billTo.setCountry('USA');

    var shipTo = new ApiContracts.CustomerAddressType();
    shipTo.setFirstName('China');
    shipTo.setLastName('Bayles');
    shipTo.setCompany('Thyme for Tea');
    shipTo.setAddress('12 Main Street');
    shipTo.setCity('Pecan Springs');
    shipTo.setState('TX');
    shipTo.setZip('44628');
    shipTo.setCountry('USA');

    var lineItem_id1 = new ApiContracts.LineItemType();
    lineItem_id1.setItemId('1');
    lineItem_id1.setName('vase');
    lineItem_id1.setDescription('cannes logo');
    lineItem_id1.setQuantity('18');
    lineItem_id1.setUnitPrice(45.00);

    var lineItem_id2 = new ApiContracts.LineItemType();
    lineItem_id2.setItemId('2');
    lineItem_id2.setName('vase2');
    lineItem_id2.setDescription('cannes logo2');
    lineItem_id2.setQuantity('28');
    lineItem_id2.setUnitPrice('25.00');

    var lineItemList = [];
    lineItemList.push(lineItem_id1);
    lineItemList.push(lineItem_id2);

    var lineItems = new ApiContracts.ArrayOfLineItem();
    lineItems.setLineItem(lineItemList);

    var userField_a = new ApiContracts.UserField();
    userField_a.setName('A');
    userField_a.setValue('Aval');

    var userField_b = new ApiContracts.UserField();
    userField_b.setName('B');
    userField_b.setValue('Bval');

    var userFieldList = [];
    userFieldList.push(userField_a);
    userFieldList.push(userField_b);

    var userFields = new ApiContracts.TransactionRequestType.UserFields();
    userFields.setUserField(userFieldList);

    var transactionSetting1 = new ApiContracts.SettingType();
    transactionSetting1.setSettingName('duplicateWindow');
    transactionSetting1.setSettingValue('120');

    var transactionSetting2 = new ApiContracts.SettingType();
    transactionSetting2.setSettingName('recurringBilling');
    transactionSetting2.setSettingValue('false');

    var transactionSettingList = [];
    transactionSettingList.push(transactionSetting1);
    transactionSettingList.push(transactionSetting2);

    var transactionSettings = new ApiContracts.ArrayOfSetting();
    transactionSettings.setSetting(transactionSettingList);

    var transactionRequestType = new ApiContracts.TransactionRequestType();
    transactionRequestType.setTransactionType(ApiContracts.TransactionTypeEnum.AUTHCAPTURETRANSACTION);
    transactionRequestType.setPayment(paymentType);
    transactionRequestType.setAmount(utils.getRandomAmount());
    transactionRequestType.setLineItems(lineItems);
    transactionRequestType.setUserFields(userFields);
    transactionRequestType.setOrder(orderDetails);
    transactionRequestType.setTax(tax);
    transactionRequestType.setDuty(duty);
    transactionRequestType.setShipping(shipping);
    transactionRequestType.setBillTo(billTo);
    transactionRequestType.setShipTo(shipTo);
    transactionRequestType.setTransactionSettings(transactionSettings);

    var createRequest = new ApiContracts.CreateTransactionRequest();
    createRequest.setMerchantAuthentication(merchantAuthenticationType);
    createRequest.setTransactionRequest(transactionRequestType);

    //pretty print request
    console.log(JSON.stringify(createRequest.getJSON(), null, 2));

    var ctrl = new ApiControllers.CreateTransactionController(createRequest.getJSON());
    //Defaults to sandbox
    //ctrl.setEnvironment(SDKConstants.endpoint.production);

    ctrl.execute(function(){

        var apiResponse = ctrl.getResponse();

        var response = new ApiContracts.CreateTransactionResponse(apiResponse);

        //pretty print response
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));

        if(response != null){
            if(response.getMessages().getResultCode() == ApiContracts.MessageTypeEnum.OK){
                if(response.getTransactionResponse().getMessages() != null){
                    console.log('Successfully created transaction with Transaction ID: ' + response.getTransactionResponse().getTransId());
                    console.log('Response Code: ' + response.getTransactionResponse().getResponseCode());
                    console.log('Message Code: ' + response.getTransactionResponse().getMessages().getMessage()[0].getCode());
                    console.log('Description: ' + response.getTransactionResponse().getMessages().getMessage()[0].getDescription());
                }
                else {
                    console.log('Failed Transaction.');
                    if(response.getTransactionResponse().getErrors() != null){
                        console.log('Error Code: ' + response.getTransactionResponse().getErrors().getError()[0].getErrorCode());
                        console.log('Error message: ' + response.getTransactionResponse().getErrors().getError()[0].getErrorText());
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                console.log('Failed Transaction. ');
                if(response.getTransactionResponse() != null && response.getTransactionResponse().getErrors() != null){

                    console.log('Error Code: ' + response.getTransactionResponse().getErrors().getError()[0].getErrorCode());
                    console.log('Error message: ' + response.getTransactionResponse().getErrors().getError()[0].getErrorText());
                }
                else {
                    console.log('Error Code: ' + response.getMessages().getMessage()[0].getCode());
                    console.log('Error message: ' + response.getMessages().getMessage()[0].getText());
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            console.log('Null Response.');
        }

        callback(response);
    });
}

if (require.main === module) {
    chargeCreditCard(function(){
        console.log('chargeCreditCard call complete.');
    });
}

module.exports.chargeCreditCard = chargeCreditCard;
```

cart.ts

````
    let total = item.price * item.quantity;
    item.options.forEach(option => (total += option.value * item.quantity));
    return total;
  }

  get totalAmount() {
    let total = 0;
    this.cart.forEach(item => (total += this.getItemTotal(item)));
    return total;
  }```


 


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibUDr.png
````

Comment: Stripe offers stripe.js as a client-side library. It uses a secure iframe in your app, and ensures that payment-card secrets (number, expiration, cvc) never touch your servers and are inaccessible from your client javascript. And, it has a sweet UI.  That's what you want. Authorize.net has accept.js to do the same thing.

Comment: This is very helpful.

Comment: Any idea how to change this to use accept.js?

Comment: I have a stackblitz working with Accet.Js Ollie. Could you let me know if you are able to help out? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7tneqi?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhero.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using the accept suite seems to be the most logical answer